# Certain Media Wont Work

Tags: codecs

Recently, my computer stopped being able to play mp4, 3pg, avi, mkv, and more media. VLC will get it to work, nothing else does, and when I try to play it with the normal player it always tries to find codecs to install, when just yesterday everything worked fine

Comment: Have you done any upgrade or something ?..

Comment: Perhaps, either way... I'd just like to play my files again

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the ubuntu-restricted-extras package installed, as well as the gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse and gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse packages.  You can find them in Software Center; if they don't show up there go to edit->Software Sources and make sure you have Multiverse enabled.

Comment: All is installed, yet no luck

Comment: I've reinstalled the things and everything, yet no luck

Comment: To be clear Totem is the program you're using that isn't working, yes?  Do you have any PPAs enabled?